# MVC View - Date Format Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

While Binding data to `TextBox`, I want to convert it to `dd/MM/yyyy` format. In the Following Code, `HolidayDate` can be in any format which comes from db.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].HolidayDate, new { @class = "datepicker", @value = @Model[i].HolidayDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })
```

The date doesn't get converted to `dd/MM/yyyy`. How to Convert the date in a particular format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].HolidayDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker", @value = @Model[i].HolidayDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })
```